# GCC does not do default type conversion inside printf

Tags: c, gcc, type-conversion

I was wondering why gcc does not support its default type conversions inside the `printf` function. For example:

```
printf("%f",(7/2));
```

gets undefined behaviour because it is expecting a float but getting an Integer value.

But in case of  assignment like -- `float f=7/2;` it does type conversion by default.

What is the reason behind not supporting default type conversion inside `printf`?  I am not asking about C specification I am asking about what is the logic behind such specification. It would be better if someone explain with some example.

Comment: Variadic arguments are not typesafe at all. The only indication it has that the argument is a float is your format string. Each type, when passed in as a variadic argument, has specific rules for which type it will be in the function.

Comment: Note that the assignment generates `3.0F` because the division is between to integer values, so the result is an integer, which is then converted to `float` because of the assignment.

Comment: "Why" is a difficult question to answer.  We can only hypothesise about the fact that this would mean adding a special case to the language.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Hypothesizing is not the only thing we can do. We can read the [rationale document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) produced by the committee and other documents about their work. We can reason about the effects and amount of work that a feature would require. We can write compilers ourselves to explore why it is harder to do something one way than another. In the case of `printf`, it is pretty clear that significant difficulties are introduced by requiring the compiler to convert according to the format string.

Comment: BTW, `"%f"` is for double arguments, all `float` are converted to `double` when passed to this kind of va_arg function.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Is there a web available version of the rationale document (2003) that may reflect C11?

Comment: `printf` has no business evaluating the expression `(7/2)`, it's an expression that has to be evaluated and the resulting value will be passed on to `printf`. In C, as in many other languages, too, dividing an int by an int yields an int.

Comment: @chux: I am not aware of a rationale document for C 2011. You can dive into the numerous documents of the C [working group](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C language standard does not specify that `printf` arguments are converted to the types in the format string because this would require the **compiler** to interpret the format string instead of having **printf** do it.

Some modern compilers do examine the `printf` string and issue warnings if it does not match the arguments. But this is a recent development. In the years when C was developed, compilers were simpler software than they are today, and adding the requirement that they interpret the `printf` format string would have been an unwelcome burden at that time.

Additionally, the format string is not necessarily known at compile time. You can write `printf(format, a, b, c)`, where `format` is computed at run time. Obviously, the compiler would not be able to generate simple code to convert `a`, `b`, and `c` to the types that will eventually be in the string `format`. It is theoretically possible, of course; the compiler could generate a lot of code to handle all the cases at run time. But that would be an excessive amount of work for a feature that is not needed.

Comment: +1 about "format string is not necessarily known at compile time".

Comment: @Eric your answer looks convincing. Most probably c compilers were targeted to be simple & fast. So they did't take such burden.

Answer (score 1):

The C spec mandates a lot of what 'gcc' has to do. In this case, the expression (7/2) is an integer expression in the C language, and pretending it is a float because it happens to be one of the arguments to a printf function with a (possibly wrong) format string would violate the spec in a big way, and surprise many, many veteran programmers.

If you want the value to be converted to a float, the easiest thing to do is to multiply times 1, (i.e. use `(1.0 * 7 / 2)` -- but NOT `(1.0 * (7/2))` because this will first do integer truncation -- in other words, it would turn (7/2) into 3 first, and then multiply 1.0*3 = 3.0, not the 3.5 you are expecting.

Comment: 5? The question uses 2? It affects the values, not the gist of your answer, although in this case, it would surely be easier to write either 7.0/2 or 7/2.0 or 7.0/2.0 or even just 3.5.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks - I misread the original - fixed now.

Comment: I know these basic stuffs. What I wanted the logic behind such rules.

Comment: @alienCoder: The logic is simple. The argument to `printf()` in question is one of the ones in the `...` (no determined types). Therefore the default promotion rules apply; types shorter than `int` are promoted to `int`, and `float` is promoted to `double`. That's all. There is nothing to tell the compiler (as opposed to the `printf()` function itself) that the second argument in this case needs to be a `%f`.  If you're using GCC, it will diagnose a type mismatch, but that's not required by the standard. Don't forget that this behaviour predates prototypes by a decade and more.

Comment: The question asks why the C standard specifies this.

Answer (score 0):

`7/2` results in an `int` and passed as such to `printf()`.

The `"f"` conversion specifier then tells `printf()` to pull a `double` from the stack, but it finds ... - data for an `int`, as passed in.

To behave as you expect the compiler needed to parse the format string during compile time to generate the correct code for passing the variadic arguments. It is not build this way.

And probably will never be. Imagine the format string being build during run-time ... - no chance to generate the correct code to pass the arguments.

Comment: `"%f"` is for `double`, `printf` could never handle `float`, since this is converted to `double`, anyhow, for this kind of functions.

Comment: Sure, fixed. @JensGustedt

Answer (score -2):

Format specifiers are not meant to be default type promotions. In first case

```
printf("%f",(7/2));
```

`7/2` is an `int` here by default. But the `%f` conversion specifier expects a `double`, and the mismatch invokes **undefined behavior**.
In the second case

```
float f = 7/2;
printf("%f", f);
```

`7/2` , which is of `int` type giving result `3`, is converted to the type of `f` (`3.0f`) as standard says:

**6.5.16 Assignment operators:**

> The type of an assignment expression is the type the left operand would have
>   after lvalue conversion.

The compiler automatically converts the `float` to `double` (default promotions for variable arguments) and hence fulfills the condition expected by the `printf` format specifier.

Comment: Note that the `7/2` is calculated as an `int` and the result (`3`!) is converted to `3.0F` for assignment.

Comment: The question asks why this is the case.

Comment: @EricPostpischil; Specification says nothing about this.

Comment: @haccks: So? The question does not ask what the C standard says about why it says what it says. It asks why the C standard says it. There are reasons why the C standard is the way it is, even if those reasons are not in the standard.